# TLS version issue on LB

Tags: single-sign-on, tls1.2, f5

I have one SSO application where multiple interface using this for login purpose. all are going through LB. I have already disabled TLS version < 1.2 on webservers but while disabling on LB level the interface which are using lower version are getting impacted after someday not on the sameday of change. I need to know why this is happening after someday regardless on the same day of change in LB.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you are saying, but when you make a change on a big-ip device, the currently active connections/sessions are not immediately impacted, only new connections are. So that might be what you are seeing. 

If I am not clear on the issue, please advise and I'll address.

Comment: Thanks Jason for clearing my doubt.. i was also thinking the same.